# .NET XmlSerializer: How to ensure white space from object property value as significant white space when serializing?

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I do XML serialization for objects with the **XmlSerializer**. When an object property of type string contains a white space (" "), this value is serialized as insignificant white space:

```
<tag> </tag>
```

However, I like to ensure, that this whitespace(s) are kept as significant white spaces. Say, that it would look like:

```
<tag>&nbsp;</tag>
```

or:

```
<tag xml:space="preserve"> </tag>
```

How can I achieve that with the XmlSerializer?

Comment: Maybe the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33152837/preserve-whitespace-only-element-content-when-deserializing-xml-using-xmlseriali) from **Panagiotis Kanavos** will help you.

Comment: @PhilippApe: I guess, you mean the possiblity to decorate class members with XML serialization directives. Unfortunately, the objects which I'm serializing, are generic, so I cannot add any serializiation information on object's class members ...

Comment: Another solution is to override the behavior of your `XmlWriter` (supplied for your `XmlSerializer`), see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26017833/serializing-options-for-non-breaking-spaces).

Comment: @Philipp Ape: Thanks for this hint. Yes I was able to adjust the XML export with XMLSerializer when using a XmlWriter. It worked ok for spaces when I used the XmlWriter to write an entity instead of a real space character, but it turned out, that I'm unable to preserve carriage return and/or line feed even if I use an entity, they always got lost. Currently I read the XML with explicit preserving spaces: not very ellegant, but that works ...